# C# check if ref List<> contents have changed

Tags: c#, list, events, ref

Say for example I have this in a class:

```
List<int> myIntegerList;

public MyClass(ref List<int> intList)
{
    myIntegerList= intList;
}
```

And this in my main class:

```
List<int> myIntegerList = new List<int>();
MyClass myNewClass;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myIntegerList .Add(Random.Next(0, 100));
}

myNewClass = new MyClass(ref IntegerList);
```

Is there an easy way to check in the `myNewClass` object if the contents of the referenced `List<int>` has changed? e.g. If any of the random integers in the list change then raise an event in the `myNewClass` object.

Comment: Use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`. Also, don't use `ref`. In C#, `myIntegerList` is *already* a reference to an object. Just pass in the reference.

Comment: You don't need to use `ref`.  You'd only need that if you wanted to assign the passed in parameter to something else and have that change the variable that you passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<T>` won't do that, but `ObservableCollection<T>` will. Also, don't use a `ref` parameter in a constructor; any C# variable referring to a class instance is a reference already. `ref` parameters of a class type are a reference *to* a reference, which you don't want and probably don't want to think about either.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class MyClass
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> _integerList;

    //  Do not make this a ref parameter, it's a reference already
    public MyClass(ObservableCollection<int> intList)
    {
        _integerList = intList;
        _integerList.CollectionChanged += _integerList_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void _integerList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //  Do stuff here in response to changed values in the list. 

        //  Now back to the reference thing again: int is immutable.
        //  You can't change it, you can only replace it with another 
        //  int. This event will be raised when you do that. 
        //
        //  If the objects in the ObservableCollection are class 
        //  instances rather than ints, they're mutable. You can 
        //  change their properties without replacing them. 
        //  ObservableCollection cannot know when that happens, so 
        //  it can't tell you. 
        //
        //  In that case, you'd need the class to implement 
        //  INotifyPropertyChanged. That's a different can of worms, 
        //  but it's a manageable one. 
    }
}
```

...

```
ObservableCollection<int> ints = new ObservableCollection<int>();
MyClass myNewClass;
var r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ints.Add(r.Next(0, 100));
}

myNewClass = new MyClass(ints);
```

Comment: Had to update a 4 year-old code base to make it work, but it was worth it. Thanks!

Another quick question, is there a way to use ref to make sure that when an item is removed from a List it is also removed from another List? Basically I'd like to have one List contain a reference to an item in another List and be able to remove both simultaneously without having to use events.

Comment: @GryffDavid Does it absolutely have to be two different collection objects? It can be done, but I'd much rather do that by just sharing a single collection around.

Comment: It's a bit of a weird situation. It's for a game. The second List only has to contain a few items from the original List and the same items in the original List might end up being removed at any point and I need the change to echo to the second List.

Comment: @GryffDavid I'd look at a filtered CollectionView: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use ObservableCollection..check out the below link for further reference

[ObservableCollection msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365(v=vs.110).aspx)